# MongoDB Error "MustAuthenticateFirst" with React App

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I'm currently working on a small project thats supposed to teach me how to properly implement databases. It is supposed to be a small userlist with "currency" and items. Since I'm still a beginner I wasn't too confident in creating everything from scratch, so I am currently using **React, MongoDB and Stitch**.

When I'm working on the app on my development server, everything works fine. It connects and displays the proper data without any kind of error. But once I tried hosting it online, I got an error: [Error Message: "MustAuthenticateFirst"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z2k8.png).

**Code**

```js
export const Bank = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

  function initializeClient() {
    const client = Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("xxxx");
    const mongodb = client.getServiceClient(
      RemoteMongoClient.factory,
      "mongodb-atlas"
    );
    const db = mongodb.db("nnbank");
    displayBankOnLoad(client, db);
  }

  function displayBankOnLoad(client, db) {
    client.auth
      .loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential())
      .then(displayBank(db))
      .catch(console.error);
  }

  function displayBank(db) {
    db.collection("user")
      .find()
      .toArray()
      .then(user => {
        setUser(user);
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }

  useEffect(() => initializeClient(),[]);
```

I can't seem to find the reason for this error and I couldn't find any solution online yet. So if you guys have any idea, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself after doing some digging in the code.

I was under the assumption, that a one time auth was enough and a later query completely slipped my mind.

Once I authenticated this query as well, everything runs smoothly.